# Is it necessary to ask permission for both Read and Write in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

My React Native app need to create a folder in app level storage in Document dir. For first launch app should ask permission and create the folder .
But when I run any one of READ and WRITE permission the another becomes true.(If READ is grandest the WRITE is also granted and vice versa)

I wonder if either READ or WRITE permission is enough for both READ and WRITE. Is it guaranteed that all the supported android version(API 23 and later) of RN will behave same in REACT NATIVE app or should I ask for both permissions ?

React has listed permission and there is no common permission for READ and WRITE.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid#permissions-that-require-prompting-the-user

This code seems redundant. What would be the good way to ensure we get R and W permissions.

```js
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: "Storage reading permissions",
          message:
            "To show stickers the app need storage read permission" +
            "",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      const granted2 = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        {
          title: "Storage writting permissions",
          message:
            "To create stickers the app need storage read permission" +
            "",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can read");
      } else {
        console.log("Read permission denied");
      }

      if (granted2 === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can write");
      } else {
        console.log("writting permission denied");
      }
```

Comment: In general, WRITE access also grants READ on most OSes.  Android included.  The reverse is definitely not true.  Now it is possible that RN is coded to ask for both when it only wants one.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the good way to ask permission of both read and write in less code.

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

let permission = [
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
]    

let status = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(permissions)

if (status = PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
    // granted
}else{
   // Not granted
}
```